# Disable drag and drop events in SharePoint calendars

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to disable drag and drop event in SharePoint calendar? I looked all available properties in SPCalendar control but I didn't find any.

Rendered Javascript has a parameter in factory class which control this behavior but not sure if I can access it through code behind or Javascript:

```
SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarContainerFactory.create(document.getElementById('ctl00_m_g_67e2a6e7_070b_4dbd_8082_cdb772ec594e_ctl00_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00'),{ctxId:'WPQ1',dataSources:[{id:'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',name:'',color:'',formUrl:'\u002fLists\u002fCorpCalendar\u002fDispForm.aspx',primary:true, **disableDrag:true**}],userInfo:{current:{id:'27',loginName:'ACME\\Test',displayName:'Test',email:'Test@acme.com'}},enablePeople:false,enableResource:false,usePostBack:false,canUserCreateItem:true,sharedPickerClientId:null,reservationContentTypeId:'0x0102004F51EFDEA49C49668EF9C6744C8CF87D',aM12String:'12:00 am',serviceUrl:'\u002f_layouts\u002fCalendarService.ashx'},'day','',[{"Options":41,"Table":null,"DatePicker":null,"Dates":["12/12/2011","12/13/2011"],"RangeJDay":[150094,150094],"Navs":null,"Items":{"Data":[[0,1,2,150094,150094,3,3,4,5,12,0,30,0,0,0,2,6]],"Strings":["1158","Test Meeting","","12/12/2011","12:00 pm","12:30 pm","0x7fffffffffffffff"]}}]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May have better luck at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am providing link to answers provide by Kai on sharepoint.stackexchange.com:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25321/disable-drag-and-drop-events-in-sharepoint-calendars